# get parent_category class in loop

Tags: categories

I'm trying to have the `parent_category` class in my loop. I've tried this:

```
<a href="#" class="<?php $parent = get_category($cat); echo $parent->category_nicename;?>">
    <?php single_cat_title('') ?>
</a>
```

and many other instead of `$parent` but can not make this work. How can I show the parent category class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would need to check if the category has children, if it does then we can show a few things. Below is a helpful function to check just that.

```
function category_has_children( $term_id = 0, $post_type = 'post', $taxonomy = 'category' ) {
    $children = get_categories( array( 'child_of' => $term_id, 'type' => $post_type, 'taxonomy' => $taxonomy ) );
    return ( $children );
}
```

By adding this somewhere in your `functions.php` file, you can then call it and pass it a few things. It returns either `true` the category does have children or `false` if not. <s>Below I'm assuming the `$cat` that you're passing into `get_category()` in your question above is a parent category ID, if not you need to somehow get the parent ID ( if `$cat` is an object, check if `$cat->parent` is something other than 0 ).</s> If `$cat` has a parent we know it has children, if the parent is 0, we must check if it has children.

```
<?php
    $cat           = get_queried_object();
    $classes        = "current_{$cat->slug}";
    if( 0 == $cat->parent ) {
        $classes   .= ( category_has_children( $cat->term_id ) ? ' has_children' : '' );
    } else {
        $parent     = get_category( $cat->parent );
        $classes    = "parent_{$parent->slug} is_child";
        $classes   .= ( category_has_children( $cat->term_id ) ? ' has_children' : '' );
    }
?>
    <a href="#" class="<?php echo $classes; ?>"><?php echo single_cat_title( '' ); ?></a>
```

First we apply a class of the current category. **IF** the current category does not have a parent ( is a top-level category ) then we check if it has children and apply a class if it does. **ELSE** the current category *does* have a parent so we first get the parent and add 2 classes, 1 of the parent slug and another letting us know that it is a child. Finally, **IF** the child category also has children, add the class `has_children` **ELSE** do nothing.

---

[`get_queried_object()` Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) - This will explain it in more depth but basically ( pulled from The Codex ) will get some generic information:

- if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
- if you're on a page, it will return the page object
- if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
- if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object

Comment: Hi Thank you, 

I' mtrying to make it work ... It's fine for the parent_category. However, when it's a chidl category, it give the class 'no_children' i woudl like to give the parent_category slug when it's a child category . ..  do you know how to make this work ? THank you got your help

Comment: @user3439889 Try my edit, the `$classes` uses a [short-hand `if-else`](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples) so you would want to add your child classes on the `:` ( else ) statement.

Comment: hm whith your edit ti display the class of the current category_slug ..  not the parent slug :(

Do you ahve any other help :( ?

What i want is to display only the current parent_slug :(

Comment: @user3439889 What's the exact classes it's showing? Both the true and the false if the `if-else` show the parent slug, *if* `$cat` is indeed the parent as it appears in your original question.

Comment: its showing: 'no_children child_of_money-saving'

So money_saving is my current child_category . . . Id like to show instead the parent_category of money_saving . . .which is business-finance... :(

Comment: @user3439889 It looks like that `$cat` *is not* your parent category as your question suggests so I've added a conditional to check if we're currently viewing a parent category or not. You can try that, feel free to play around with the code to add classes to get it to work for you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you again for your help . .. Ive try to play around  .. but he original new code seem to break my loop .. .  it doesnt display anymore my post . .. :(

Comment: @user3439889 whoops, had a syntax error. That should work now.

Comment: thank you for that . . . it still doesnt display the slug but only 'current_ has_children' as a class . . .:( :( :( :( Im really sorry to ask you so much ..  . but im just having headache since a week with that . . .

Comment: @user3439889 try adding this line above the first `$class` line: `$cat = get_queried_object();`

Comment: You are awesome !!! Thank you so much it works perfectly :) you rock !

Comment: can i know what does this do basically ?     $cat     = get_queried_object();

Comment: @user3439889 Definitely! I'll edit my question to explain it a little bit.

Comment: thank you :) it s good to know :) really appreciate your time !